# How to resolve the error in oozie compilation

Tags: oozie

I'm getting the following error in `oozie` compilation.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
(default-compile) on project oozie-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/oozie/.m2/repository/javax/jdo/jdo2-api/2.3-ec/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar; error in opening zip file.
```

Please help me to rectify this.

Comment: Can you provide the information about the `Oozie` repository, branch and command you are running to compile/install the Oozie.

Comment: Iam getting the error when running the following command "sudo -u oozie ./mkdistro.sh"

Comment: Can you first go to Oozie project directory and execute the command 'mvn clean compile' and see just this goes fine.

Comment: ok I will try in the afternoon when the system is available and let u know.

Comment: Iam getting the following error while executing mvn clean compile Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project oozie-client: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/wcbdd/apache/oozie-3.3.1/client/target/oozie-client-3.3.1-client/oozie-client-3.3.1/DISCLAIMER.txt -> [Help 1]

Comment: Not sure, what is happening. Do you have write permissions to oozie project directory. You use the `-X` option for more log. `mvn clean compile -X`.

Comment: have you installed oozie with your user ? it seems you don't have write permission.

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine.